# Issue when Open fire version update from 4.0.0 to 4.7.3

Tags: openfire

When we update open fire version from 4.0.0 to 4.7.3, getting exception “could not load open fire settings plugin, please check if SQL server port is configured as per install guide instructions and click retry or click cancel” Please share your suggestions to fix this issue.

Tried to update Openfire 4.0.0 version to Openfire 4.7.3 version. tried to reset the setup change to false in openfire.xml you can set up whole information and database from start.

Answer (score 0):

> could not load open fire settings plugin, please check if SQL server port is configured as per install guide instructions and click retry or click cancel

This message, assuming that it is a verbatim copy of what you see, is not generated by Openfire. I suspect that this installation is using a customization that is causing this problem.

My suggestion would be to find the source of that message.